# Changing the values of a pandas dataframe based on another

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 pandas dataframes.

DF1:

```
    hasCode?     Code
0   yes          2051 
1   no           2052  
2   no           2053 
3   no           2086
4   yes          2418
...
```

DF2:

```
   Class      2051    2052    2053   2086    2418   ...
0              x                               x  
1             
2                      x        x     
3              x       x                        x  
...
```

I need the result to look like the following:
DF3:

```
   Class      2051    2052    2053   2086    2418   ...
0   Yes       yes                            no  
1   empty          
2   no                no       no    
3   Yes        yes    no                     no  
...
```

The x's need to change to yes' and no;s, while the class column changes with what was given. basically if there is a yes in df1, then mark a yes in the corresponding column, and make the values of class yes.  If the value form DF! is no, then change the x's to no, and change the value of class to no as well.

I've tried the following

- the .existsin() but I couldnt figure out the logic.
- Combining them into one dataframe and doing it that way, but pandas wont let me combine them together on the same rows, it stacks the df
- I tried writing a function that goes through the dataframe and saves value and then changes those values in the second dataframe,

Nothing has worked.

Comment: Could you show your efforts and describe the specific problem you are struggling with?

Comment: Sure, I just edited it!

Comment: why 2051 is set to yes in the last row??

Answer (score 0):

Let's prepare the data:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data1 = '''
    hasCode     Code
0   yes          2051 
1   no           2052  
2   no           2053 
3   no           2086
4   yes          2418
'''

df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data1), delim_whitespace=True)

data2 = '''
   Class      2051     2052     2053    2086    2418 
0  nan        x        nan      nan     nan     x  
1  nan        nan      nan      nan     nan     nan
2  nan        nan      x        x       nan     nan
3  nan        x        x        nan     nan     x 
'''

df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data2), delim_whitespace=True)
```

`Yes` and `No` are used here as a logical value `True` and `False`. So we can replace them like that. But for the purpose of keeping in place `NaN` values, it's better to use numerical arithmetic. So I'm gonna replace them with 1 and 0. I'm gonna replaxe `x` in the `df2` frame with 1. Therefore, when multiplying on the code's value `hasCode` we get the code back with no changes to `NaN` values:

```
codes = (
    df1
    # make the codes the same type as corresponding values in df2.columns
    # before putting them into index; we need this as well as squeezing
    # to easily apply element-wise multiplication on the next step
    .astype({'Code': str})   
    .set_index('Code')
    .squeeze()
    .replace({'yes': 1, 'no': 0})
)

df3 = df2.drop('Class', axis='columns').replace({'x': 1}) * codes.values
```

Now we apply `df3.any(...)` to check if there's any value 1 in a row, and assign that to `df3['Class']` column. Info about empty rows will be lost, so we have to keep it in a separate value:

```
empty = df3.isna().all('columns')   # mark rows with all empty cells
df3['Class'] = df3.any(axis='columns').astype(float)    # need astype to stick with 1 and 0 only (easier to replace later)

df3 = df3.replace({1:'Yes', 0:'No'})
df3.loc[empty, 'Class'] = 'Empty'

df3 = df3.reindex(columns=df2.columns)   # restore the original order of columns
```

The final output:

[image: resulting frame]